# Goldbach-like conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers

While experimenting, I found that every number up to $200000$, with the sole exception of $216$ is the sum of a prime and a triangular number (where $0$ and $1$ are included as prime). Is anything known about this?

Comment: Why are $0$ and $1$ included as prime? They are not prime.

Comment: Yes: http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3737
Also [oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=sum+of+prime+and+triangular+number&language=english&go=Search) has something

Comment: Should be reformulated as: is the sum of triagular and prime or is triangular or is triangular +1. Checking only up to 200000 and already finding one counterexample seems not very promising to me.

Comment: Confirmed up to 10 million with the only exception being 216 (as stated by the OP)

Comment: @E.O. Did you happen to check up to higher numbers?